# Drools Fusion Event Processing LRU eviction

Tags: drools, drools-fusion, drools-kie-server

I am using Drools Fusion for processing large scale events of millions of users.

Since volume of events is huge , it will lead to out of memory error if I keep on adding incoming events in kie session.
Each event is associated with User. Is it possible to evict events from session based on user's LRU policy ?

Any sample code will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you could write some rules that will delete the events from working memory based on user's LRU policy.

e.g. something like if event has the policy in it

```
rule "retract event"
when 
    User($userPolicy: policy == somePolicy)
    $event: Event(policy == $userPolicy)
then
    delete($event);
end
```

Comment: when will the policy be evaluated , like can I set on each event check working memory size and if size >threshold - remove events older than configured time. Can I get filter events based on (insertion time-now) and what will be complexity or performance impact of that.

Comment: Do you mean when this rule will be evaluated? If so, then it is evaluated during fire, like all previous rules. For handling continuous fire you can use fireUntilHalt() method. Please see the docs here https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.3.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_active_mode. Hmm as I am thinking if you need to remove the oldest events, setting events expiration might also help you. See the docs here: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.3.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#__expires_time_interval